# Create and Download txt file using JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to make an AJAX call to PHP function that creates a txt file and download it.

```
 if (isset($_POST["download_file"]))
{
    $filename = "sequence.txt";
    $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $content="q";
    fwrite($f, $content);
    fclose($f);
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($filename);
}
```

This is my PHP code and here is AJAX code

```
$.ajax(
{
        url:"./apis/download_seq.php",
        data:{download_file:"true",sequence:seq},
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){
        }
});
```

And this is AJAX call. Problem is that my current code saves file on server. Like it create sequence.txt file in directory where my PHP file is located.
I want to download it to client side i.e. to my browser.

Comment: So echo instead of write. Remember to set the content-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little out from PHP but something like that for PHP side:

This part could be skipped:

```
$f = fopen($filename, 'w');
$content="q";
fwrite($f, $content);
fclose($f);
```

And if file is not huge, you can replace that with simple variable:

```
$text = "q";
$text = $text."new text";
```

At the end:

```
readfile($filename);
```

Replace with:

```
echo($text);
```

I DID NOT TEST THIS :) so make a test.

For Jquery part there is a lot of answers there:
[Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)